# Reorder Factor in rCharts dPlot

Tags: r, rcharts

How to do I reorder the factor in my `dPlot`, as such that "Exceptional" is located at the most left, followed by "Fine", "Mediocre", "Trouble", "Danger", and "Critical".

Dataset:

```
dat<-structure(list(MainDept = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("Business Development", 
"Finance Department", "HR & Admin Department", "Manufacturing & Engineering Department", 
"QA Department", "Supply Chain Department"), class = "factor"), 
    Level = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("Critical", 
    "Danger", "Exceptional", "Fine", "Mediocre", "Trouble"), class = "factor"), 
    Freq = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 29L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 108L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 15L, 0L, 7L, 15L, 16L, 73L, 59L, 12L, 
    0L, 0L, 191L, 0L, 0L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 128L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("MainDept", 
"Level", "Freq"), row.names = c(NA, -36L), class = "data.frame")
```

The code to generate the plot:

```
require(rCharts)
plot<-dPlot(y="MainDept", x="Freq",data=dat,groups="Level",type="bar",width=1200)
plot$yAxis(type="addCategoryAxis")
plot$xAxis(type="addPctAxis")
plot$legend(
  x = 0,
  y = 0,
  horizontalAlign = "right"
)
```

I tried with:

```
dat$Level<-as.character(dat$Level)
dat$Level[dat$Level=="Exceptional"]<-1
dat$Level[dat$Level=="Fine"]<-2
dat$Level[dat$Level=="Mediocre"]<-3
dat$Level[dat$Level=="Trouble"]<-4
dat$Level[dat$Level=="Danger"]<-5
dat$Level[dat$Level=="Critical"]<-6
dat$Level<-as.factor(dat$Level)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about `dPlot`, but if it relies on the order of the levels in the grouping variable you should try

```
dat$Level <- factor(dat$Level, levels = c("Exceptional", "Fine", "Mediocre", 
                                          "Trouble", "Danger", "Critical"))
```

As I do not know in which library `dPlot` can be found this is of course untested. Hence, for future reference, a minimal working example including the necessary libraries would help.

Comment: There is a package called `rCharts` dPlot is a part of it. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. It is not solving my questions.